# Binding Error When Trying to Cascade Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

So I have 4 UserControls on top of each other. Since I got confused a little, I got an image below:

[image]

The ViewModelLocator is in UserControl 1. The goal is to provide each UserControl with their own ViewModel. For UserControl 2 and 3, I managed to provide their ViewModels (for UserControl 3 I used a DependencyProperty). But for UserControl 4, I tried to cascade Dependency Properties lying in UserControl 2 and UserControl 3 to provide the ViewModel for UserControl 4. However I encountered an error:

> A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Below is a link to the archived copy of the sample solution that replicates this issue.

[MvvmLight2.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/14vyewwl18dqbxn/MvvmLight2.zip)

Comment: You are trying to bind a property that is not a dependency property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the property is a dependency property. As I mentioned above, I tried to provide UserControl 4's ViewModel by creating a dependency property on UserControl 2 and UserControl 3 and cascading them to give UserControl 1 a way to do that. So it's like ViewModelLocator (UserControl 1) > DependencyProperty (UserControl 2) > DependencyProperty (UserControl 3) > DataContext (UserControl 4)

Comment: The compiler disagrees, show us your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for paying good attention to this issue that I'm having. I tried to replicate the same scenario on a sample solution. This time I really made sure that they're indeed dependency properties. Same issue occurred. I attached the sample solution above.

Comment: Runs just fine, only removed reverences to `PInfoSysH.dll`...

Comment: That's weird. It always encounters problems in Blend and it's always considered as an error in Designer. Did you do anything else aside from removing the reference to PInfoSysH.dll?

Comment: I tried to play with it a little and this what happened: I removed this line and built the project: mvvmView1="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MvvmView1}" mvvmView2="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MvvmView2}" then afterwards i pasted it again. The expected output in Blend appeared. But after I built it again with those code included, the errors appeared again and the Blend had errors too.

Comment: I do not care one bit about GUI designer tool errors...

Comment: I'm sorry but it really does not work like you said on my end. I didn't change anything aside from removing the reference to PInfoSysH.dll. I tried to ignore the errors on Blend and the Designer and tried to debug the application. But it reports an error on that same line exactly where the bindings are.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. After a few hours looking at and playing with the code, I managed to make it work even with designer tool errors. But why is it having errors even though it works?